# What controls php error_log file properties (permissions, owner, group) on linux?

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a Linux environment running Apache/PHP which includes a php script that calls on the php command

```
error_log($tx,3,$pathandfilenm)
```

The result is an error file with the given path/filename, but it has permissions showing

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root      root      161445 Jan 25 00:00 myErrorFile.log.2017-01-25
```

This file is built automatically by php if it doesn't already exist; does anyone know how I can control the owner and group for this file when it's built (as opposed to running some followup scripts to chase new files)?

Thanks
Abe

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess the group and owner are the same as the user (and its group) that is running the Apache/PHP mentioned.
The rights set are most probably result of the umask.

[More here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44542/what-is-umask-and-how-does-it-work)